# Set a Link into a Js var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, hyperlink

I do struggle somehow, as mentioned I need to put a Link into a var in js, so that it will open only when clicked on this item.

Js part looks as follow:

```
var items = [{
    'icon': 'new',
    'name': 'test',
    'date': 'today',
    'user': {
        'name': 'test',
        'color': '#07D5E5'
    }
}];
```

And part of Html output like this:

```
    <pager total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" 
     ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng change="pageChanged()"></pager>
      <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage < totalItems">
        Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} - 
     {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage }} of {{ totalItems }} total items
      </p>
      <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage >= totalItems">
        Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} -
      {{ totalItems }} of {{ totalItems }} total items
      </p>
```

How do I set in this Js a link which will open when someone will click on the name : test? I dont get it

Comment: Where do you like to place the link? And what should happen when you click it?

Comment: @AWolf Well, it should be in the js code individual to each name, since this is just one line of manys and should only execute when I would click on the Name test. After I clicked on it, it should either open a link like http://something in the same or new tab, which doesnt matter. If you need an example of the actuall test site it is currently running to maybe better understand it, hit me up

Comment: You have only showed the paging bit of html. Nothing related to your `var items`

Comment: no. that won't do any good...that is the output. to help solve your problem, we'd need to see the html before it gets rendered. posting a link to a live or test site doesn't help somebody in the future who arrives at this question by searching only to find a link to a site that is now working

Comment: @ethorn10 Didn't thought about that one sorry, uploaded it to cssdeck as it is http://cssdeck.com/labs/oqauoj4z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest updating the structure of your items variable to include a url property and a target property:

```
var items = [{
    'icon': 'new',
    'name': 'test',
    'url': 'http://some.actual.url/',
    'target': '_blank',
    'date': 'today',
    'user': {
        'name': 'test',
        'color': '#07D5E5'
    }
}];
```

Then in your angular:

```
<span class="grid-title">
    <a href="{{ item.url }}" target="{{ item.target }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, does work as intended to be. Unfortunately I can't upvote it, since it require 15 reputation ;) Just because I'm curious, how it would look like if it should open in a _blank Tab?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which makes use of various ng attributes and includes your item to make use of them:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.totalItems = 100;

        var items = [{
            'icon': 'new',
                'name': 'test',
                'date': 'today',
                'user': {
                'name': 'test',
                    'color': '#07D5E5'
            }
        }];

        $scope.otherItems = [{
            'icon': 'old',
                'name': 'other',
                'date': 'yesterday',
                'user': {
                'name': 'other',
                    'color': '#02D0E0'
            }
        }];

        $scope.redirect = function(name) {
            if (name == 'test') {
                window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948701/set-a-link-into-a-js-var';
            }
        };

        showItems = [];

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                $scope.otherItems.push(i == 5 ? items[0] : $scope.otherItems[0]);
            }
        }
        init();

    });
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" 
     ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <pager total-items="totalItems" 
           items-per-page="itemsPerPage" 
           ng-model="currentPage" 
           max-size="maxSize" 
           ng-change="pageChanged()"></pager>
    <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage < totalItems">Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} - {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage }} of {{ totalItems }} total items</p>
    <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage >= totalItems">Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} - {{ totalItems }} of {{ totalItems }} total items</p>
    <p ng-repeat="i in otherItems track by $index" 
       ng-if="$index < itemsPerPage * currentPage && $index > itemsPerPage * (currentPage-1)" 
       ng-click="redirect(i['name'])" 
       ng-style="{'text-decoration':(i['name'] == 'test' ? 'underline' : '')}">{{i['name']}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```